# How to make action button eventReactive() to multiple slide bars in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, r-leaflet

I am trying to let shiny do a calculation with slide bar values after the user clicks on the action button. These slide bars represent five dimensions which the user can drag to set his preferred weight value per variable. After the action button has been clicked, the app should then show a map of The Netherlands with the municipalities that have the highest 'score' based on these weight values. At the moment I've got the following code running, but very slowly after you click the Action Button, as it will automatically re-execute when the reactive slide bars change. Does someone have a suggestion to make my code faster and the action button eventReactive so that it has to be clicked to let shiny know to do a new calculation?

I've included a gist link to my main script since I could not think of an easier way to share my data (spatialpolygonsdataframe): https://gist.github.com/anonymous/602948bce91e61f36fd3eb0c4259d26c

Screenshot of Shiny app: https://i.stack.imgur.com/k0Vg9.png

app.R

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Quality-of-life-o-meter of The Netherlands"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      h3("Dimensions"),
      h6("Assign a weight value for every dimension and press the 'find!' button"),
      sliderInput("housingslider", 
                  label = h4("Housing"), 
                  min = 1, 
                  max = 5, 
                  value = 1),
      sliderInput("populationslider", 
                  label = h4("Population"), 
                  min = 1, 
                  max = 5, 
                  value = 1),
      sliderInput("provisionsslider", 
                  label = h4("Provisions"), 
                  min = 1, 
                  max = 5, 
                  value = 1),
      sliderInput("safetyslider", 
                  label = h4("Safety"), 
                  min = 1, 
                  max = 5, 
                  value = 1),
      sliderInput("physicalenvslider", 
                  label = h4("Physical Environment"), 
                  min = 1, 
                  max = 5, 
                  value = 1),
      actionButton("action", label = "Find!")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      leafletOutput("mymap", height = "800")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$mymap <-renderLeaflet({
    # Create interactive map of Total Score of Muncipalities in 2016 to display first
    leaflet(data = MunScores2016) %>% addTiles() %>%
      addPolygons(fillColor = ~pal(Total_Score_2016), 
                  fillOpacity = 1, 
                  color = 'white', 
                  weight = 1,
                  popup = popup_dat) %>%
      addLegend("bottomright", # Legend position
                pal=pal, # color palette
                values=~Total_Score_2016, # legend values
                opacity = 0.7,
                title="Percentage difference from national average")
  })  

  observeEvent(input$action,
               output$mymap <-renderLeaflet({
                 Total_Score <- NA
                 Total_Score <- ((input$housingslider * MunScores2016$Housing_Score_2016 +
                                input$populationslider * MunScores2016$Population_Score_2016 +
                                input$provisionsslider * MunScores2016$Provisions_Score_2016 +
                                input$safetyslider * MunScores2016$Safety_Score_2016 +
                                input$physicalenvslider * MunScores2016$PhysicalEnvironment_Score_2016)/
                               (input$housingslider + input$populationslider + input$provisionsslider + input$safetyslider + input$physicalenvslider))
             #Create interactive map
                 leaflet(data = MunScores2016) %>% addTiles() %>%
                   addPolygons(fillColor = ~pal(Total_Score), 
                               fillOpacity = 1, 
                               color = 'white', 
                               weight = 1,
                               popup = paste0("<strong>Municipality:</strong>", 
                                          MunScores2016$Municipality_Name, 
                                          "<br><strong>Quality-of-life-o-meter says: </strong>", 
                                          Total_Score)) %>%
                   addLegend("bottomright", # Legend position
                             pal=pal, # color palette
                             values=~Total_Score_2016, # legend values
                             opacity = 0.7,
                             title="Weighted percentage difference from national average")
               })

  )
}  
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: You should probably have only one `output$` call.  Also, if you put reactive things inside the `output$` call, the output is going to change whenever those reactive objects are changed.  You need to separate out your filters so that they only change when the action button is clicked by using `this.filter <- eventReactive(input$action, {input$sliderstuff})`.  And then call it within your output as `this.filter()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is slow because you recreate everything constantly without knowing it.

---

### Refresh

Let me address your slider-refresh issue first:

Within the `observeEvent` (which really only fires if the button is pressed), you assign a *reactive environment* to `output$mymap` (all render functions are reactive environments).

*Inside* the `renderLeaflet`, you then *name* the input parameters, on which occasion Shiny will *automatically track* those inputs as observables.

So your *assignment* for the render function is well just happening once the button is clicked, but the render function *itself* is not limited to this event, since the reactive environment lives longer than just the assignment call.

There are two ways to pull this logic out of the render function.

1) Use `isolate` around every input reference. (i.e. `isolate(input$housingslider)` ). That way you *suppress* the reactive link to the input slider and the render observable will have no more update triggers, only updating once when you create it.

```
output$mymap <-renderLeaflet({
  Total_Score <- NA
  # isolate(expr) prevents observables in expr from being subscribed to.
  Total_Score <- isolate(
    (
      input$housingslider * MunScores2016$Housing_Score_2016
      + input$populationslider * MunScores2016$Population_Score_2016  
      + input$provisionsslider * MunScores2016$Provisions_Score_2016 
      + input$safetyslider * MunScores2016$Safety_Score_2016
      + input$physicalenvslider * PhysicalEnvironment_Score_2016
    ) / (
      input$housingslider
      + input$populationslider
      + input$provisionsslider 
      +  input$safetyslider 
      + input$physicalenvslider
    )
  )

  ...
})
```

2) Better: Move your calculation of `Total_Score` *outside* of the `renderLeaflet` function. This way, the input observables don't get *named* inside the reactive environment, that is `renderLeaflet`, which then only knows the value `Total_Score`, which it cannot subscribe to. The input observables then only belong to the outer `observeEvent`, which will ignore input changes other than action button clicks.

```
observeEvent(input$action, {
  Total_Score <- NA
  # isolate(expr) prevents observables in expr from being subscribed to.
  Total_Score <- (
    input$housingslider * MunScores2016$Housing_Score_2016
    + input$populationslider * MunScores2016$Population_Score_2016  
    + input$provisionsslider * MunScores2016$Provisions_Score_2016 
    + input$safetyslider * MunScores2016$Safety_Score_2016
    + input$physicalenvslider * PhysicalEnvironment_Score_2016
  ) / (
    input$housingslider
    + input$populationslider
    + input$provisionsslider 
    +  input$safetyslider 
    + input$physicalenvslider
  )

  output$mymap <-renderLeaflet({
    # Use Total_Score here and no input$
    ...
  })
})
```

---

### Redraw

But now to the way you actually should implement this: Use `leafletProxy`!!

Each time you call `renderLeaflet`, you destroy the map object that has been used before and create a completely new map object (and creating all the tiles again, meaning fetching those resources as well). You will realize this as soon as you see that zoom and view position are reset every time.

There is a way to *reuse* the map you have created before.

The function `leafletProxy(<name>)` lets you access the map you created with `output$<name> <- renderLeaflet(...)` and gives access to all functions of a regular leaflet call.

So we rewrite your code to only have one render function at the start and no further recreation. Server function below:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  # Create Map once.
  output$mymap <-renderLeaflet({
    leaflet(data = MunScores2016)
      %>% addTiles()
      %>% addPolygons(
        fillColor = ~pal(Total_Score_2016),
        fill2Opacity = 1, 
        color = 'white', 
        weight = 1,
        popup = popup_dat)
      %>% addLegend(
        "bottomright",
        pal=pal,
        values=~Total_Score_2016,
        opacity = 0.7,
        title="Percentage difference from national average")
  })

  observeEvent(input$action, {
    Total_Score <- NA
    Total_Score <- ((input$housingslider * MunScores2016$Housing_Score_2016 +
      input$populationslider * MunScores2016$Population_Score_2016 +
      input$provisionsslider * MunScores2016$Provisions_Score_2016 +
      input$safetyslider * MunScores2016$Safety_Score_2016 +
      input$physicalenvslider * MunScores2016$PhysicalEnvironment_Score_2016)/
      (input$housingslider + input$populationslider + input$provisionsslider + input$safetyslider + input$physicalenvslider))

    # Just update the existing map
    leafletProxy("mymap")
      # This you have to do now: remove the existing polygons, before you paint new ones.
      %>% clearShapes()
      %>% addPolygons(
        fillColor = ~pal(Total_Score), 
        fillOpacity = 1, 
        color = 'white', 
        weight = 1,
        popup = paste0("<strong>Municipality:</strong>", 
          MunScores2016$Municipality_Name, 
          "<br><strong>Quality-of-life-o-meter says: </strong>", 
          Total_Score))
      # As you can see, no addLegend is needed, since the legend does not change. 
  })
}
```

Using this, all of the above refresh issues don't occur anymore, because you don't recreate a *reactive environment* for the map. Still, I thought the first part could be helpful in the future.

Comment: Hi K. Rohde, thank you for your extensive reply. That really clears up a lot! I got an error when I first tried your code however: 

"Error in derivePolygons: Polygon data not found; please provide addPolygons with data and/or lng/lat arguments." 

It appeared that addPolygons() still required a data argument, which had to be MunScores2016. It works fine now, still pretty slowly though. A disadvantage of not including addLegend is that the legend is not being updated according to the new Polygon data/colors anymore. So I think I'll have to add the legend anyway.

Comment: @rython Sorry for that, I didn't test it, because I had no data to work with.